# TableCell Multi Component Editable JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview

How to create TableView Editable with different components in columns?

Example TableView:

[image: image of example TableView]

Comment: Your question is very vague, focusing it down will help get answers. In the mean time look at the javadoc/source for CheckBoxTableCell.

Comment: OK thank you ! But the point is precisely because I don't know which way.

Comment: Look into `TextFieldTableCell`, `ComboBoxTableCell`, `CheckBoxTableCell`, `TableColumn#cellFactory`, and `TableView#editable`.